# Will the collect operation of a Flow in Kotlin be launched again when the flow is changed?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The following code comes from Android studio project with Room. I havn't tested it.

I don't know if `listIncompleted().collect{..}` will be launched again when the records in database info_table is changed, or `listIncompleted().collect {...}` is only launched once in the code below.

Could you tell me?

```
class MyService : Service() {
    private val serviceScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
         serviceScope.launch {
              listIncompleted().collect { recordList ->
                  recordList.forEach { record ->
                      // handle each record individually
                  }
              }
         }             
    }
    ...
}


@Dao
interface  RecordDao { 
    @Query("SELECT * FROM info_table where translateState != :translateState ORDER BY createdDate desc")
    fun listIncompleted(translateState: ETranslateState = ETranslateState.COMPLETED): Flow<List<RecordEntity>>
}
```

Comment: Yeah! It can be changed immediately. 
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-intro-room-flow#8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`collect { ... }` just means *"listen for items on this flow, and run this function with each of them"*. So as long as that `Flow` keeps producing items, the function passed to `collect` will keep running in response.

A *Room* query that returns a `Flow` [is an observable query](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#observable), i.e. it'll keep producing new values if the tables referenced in the query update. So when you call `listIncompleted`, you get back a `Flow` object that produces the result of the query when collected, and will continue to produce results when relevant updates happen.

You're only calling the function once to get a `Flow`, and only calling `collect` on it once, so you're only setting up one *"source"* and connecting one *"pipe"* to it - that pipe will just keep running as updates happen in the database. It's not being *"relaunched"*, it's an open tap.

But you *are* running this in `onStartCommand`, which is invoked every time you call `startService` - so it's possible you could end up launching *multiple coroutines* that fetch their own `Flow` for the same query and start collecting it, each one getting a new value to process when a relevant update happens to that common query. So watch out for that!

Answer (score 0):

Just want to point out that talking about whether `collect { }` is called again is a little ambiguous, because you might be talking about (1) the higher-order `collect` function being called repeatedly or (2) the `FlowCollector` SAM-converted lambda that you pass to it being called repeatedly.

In your code `collect()` is called a single time. But the lambda that you pass to it is called over and over on every change to the database that affects the table(s) you're querying.

It's just like how calling `list.forEach { }` is a single call to the higher-order function, but under the hood it calls your lambda over and over for each item in the iterable.